# How to use a java class in a taglib scriptlet?

Tags: jsp, exception, jstl, taglib, scriptlet

I am trying to pass an exception string from a java class into a taglib.  I take the exception from the request and pass that into a taglib that generates a div on a page with the error text.  However i am getting an error saying "e cannot be resolved" The following is my code.

```
<% MyException e = (MyException) request.getAttribute(MyFields.EXCEPTION);
   if (e != null) { 
        String warningLevel = "none";
        if(e.getEndUserMessage().contains("warningLevel")){
            warningLevel = e.getEndUserMessage().substring(e.getEndUserMessage().indexOf("warningLevel=\"") + 14, e.getEndUserMessage().indexOf("\""));
        }
%>

<e:errorcontainer warningLevel="<%=warningLevel %>">
    <e:error propertyFile="${SSOFields.ERROR_PROPERTIES}"
            alertProperty="<%=e.getEndUserMessage()%>">  //This line is where e cannot be resolved
    </e:error>
</e:errorcontainer>
<%
   }
%>
```

I am still learning things about jsp's, so any help would be amazing.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your error isn't about the variable 'e', but taglib 'e'? For example, you didn't declare it on top of the JSP file?

Answer (score 0):

You've got two potential "e" things that could not be resolved - the exception and the namespace of your taglib. You may have bugs importing the taglib into your page or application namespace, which you can quickly eliminate by renaming your exception variable.

Comment: Even if I switch the variable name, I still get that the variable cannot be resolved in the line where I set the alertProperty.  This also happens if I create a string variable and set the endUserMessage to that, and then pass the string to alertProperty. It then says that the string cannot be resolved.

Comment: Sorry - can't help you further, it's been a while since I wrote a taglib. If you have a choice over what templating technology you use, I wouldn't go for jsp and custom taglibs as there are better alternatives out there like Freemarker. JSP is so tied to the servlet architecture with implicit variables like request and response that it requires nasty hacks to do something as simple as template an html email with it. Also, you need to be a java dev to write a taglib, whereas smart html developers can write freemarker macros.